# Add new command to a specific line in crontab

Tags: linux, sed, cron, echo

I want to add this command to line 26 in crontab.

`00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now`

How do I add this command specifically to line 26 in crontab? Also, how do I make it so if there's existing text in line 26, this new line of text will replace the previous text in line 26?

Thank you.

EDIT: I tried `crontab -l | sed -i '26/00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now' | crontab -`
but it said "no input files"

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: So you want to shutdown your PC every day at 9 am? Who is going to start it again after that? And why does it need to be line 26 exactly? What happens if your crontab has fewer lines?

Comment: Why would it have to be line 26? That sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @HatLess I tried ``` crontab -l | sed -i '26/00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now' | crontab - ```

but it said "no input files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -i.bak '26s~.*~00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now~' /var/spool/cron/root
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it gives me:

sed: couldn't edit /var/spool/cron/crontabs: not a regular file

Comment: @PissedOffBanker is `crontabs` a valid user

Comment: So when I tried /var/spool/cron/root, it says No such file or directory. I believe the path is /var/spool/cron/crontabs. I tried running the command with sudo and that's when it gives the not a regular file error. If I don't run in sudo, it says permission denied.

Comment: @PissedOffBanker What user is going to run the command? As it is a shutdown command, I'd had assumed root. Whichever user you are adding the cronjob for would be the user to add at the end of the path, however, if the user does not have adequate permissions (or password bypass if running unattended), you may still face further issues.

Comment: Gotcha, I used this "sudo sed -i.bak '26s~.*~00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now~' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi" and it seemed to work! However, the command was inserted in the wrong line, it appears on line 23 instead of 26.

Comment: @PissedOffBanker The command creates a backup of your original file so you can easily revert back. Regarding the wrong line, that is very weird, `sed` does the line counting, we specify the line with `26`. Are you sure the line needed is on line 26?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, sed seems to be off by 3 lines, so when I specify line 26, it would've added the command in line 23 instead

Comment: @PissedOffBanker Is there a unique character on the line you are targetting that can be used instead of a line number?

Comment: Does it matter if the line is empty? Also, would sed create a new line if I entered a line that isn't in cron? (E.g. the last line with text is line 25 in cron. In this case, if I wanted to create a new line in 26, would sed be able to do that?)

Comment: @PissedOffBanker If you want to append to the last line, you can use `sed '$a00 09 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now' /var/spool/cron/root`  Add `-i` if it gives the output needed